# Maven - Use static variable from src/test to src/main

Tags: maven, selenium

A simple login and logout selenium test, using pagefactory is created with TestNG and it works fine while running it as a "TestNG" test. I'm migrating it to Maven and came across issues in accessing variables between different classes.

```
src/main/java
---package:myapp.pages
         Homepage.java
         LoginPage.java
---package:utilities
         CommonUtils.java
         DatabaseUtils.java

src/test/java
---package:myapp.test
         LoginTest.java (has static variable about test name)
           public static String sTestName = "Regression test - Login/Logout"
```

While using the above variable in LoginPage.java, there is a compilation error. I'm using it as

```
public static String sName=myapp.test.LoginTest.sTestName;
```

The compilation error is:
[10,22] package myapp.test does not exist

How to handle this error? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The correct way to handle this for Selenium, is to move all your code into src/test ... because it is all test code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`src/main` is where your production code lives, `src/test` is where your test code lives. The production code is to be shipped to the production environment, the test code is not. Hence, the production code should not depend on the test code. Maven enforces this for you (and your IDE will do so accordingly). There should never be a case where your production code needs to depend on something that's only known to the testing code. Now, there *are* valid scenarios in which you want behavior to be different during tests than it is for production code, and there is many strategies to do so. For example you can use a properties file (and have one with the same name in `src/test/resources` "magically" override the production one during testing), or use `set`ters to override things just during testing.

Comment: Agree with everything, except your comment "... (and your IDE will do so accordingly)." My Eclipse does not care.

Comment: The question is tagged "maven", Eclipse and IntelliJ should both be making this separation when you import a Maven project. You should not be using any other IDE for Java :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarity on test and main modules, so either I move it all within main or within test, so then from selenium testing perspective src/main/java will never get used? Will it make any difference if the AUT is prod or non prod?

Comment: It doesn't matter a whole lot, I suppose `src/test` would be fine. I say that it doesn't matter, assuming that this is then a Maven module with nothing else inside than just the Selenium stuff. (If these are reusable Selenium classes, such as page models, it'd probably be easier for them to be in `src/main`, so that they end up in the JAR and can be reused in other AUT projects.)